How to create overlay in Fo-Dicom, need code example to create and show overlay layer using fo-dicom
How to create overlay in Fo-Dicom, need code example to create and show overlay layer using fo-dicom
Created overlay using below code but Import dicom it does not show any over not sure what is mistake.
 DicomFile dicomFile = DicomFile.Open(sourceDicomFileName, FileReadOption.ReadAll);
 ushort width = dicomFile.Dataset.GetSingleValue<ushort>(DicomTag.Columns);
 ushort height = dicomFile.Dataset.GetSingleValue<ushort>(DicomTag.Rows);
 byte[] packedbitarray = Array.Empty<byte>();
 Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
 {
     var grid = new Grid { Width = width, Height = height };
     var text = new TextBlock
     {
         Text = "OVERLAY",
         FontSize = 32,
         FontWeight = FontWeights.Bold,
         HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Center
     };
     grid.Children.Add(text);
     grid.Measure(new Size(grid.Width, grid.Height));
     grid.Arrange(new Rect(new Size(grid.Width, grid.Height)));
     var rtb = new RenderTargetBitmap(
                         (int)grid.Width,
                         (int)grid.Height,
                         96,
                         96,
                         PixelFormats.Pbgra32);
     rtb.Render(grid);
     int stride = rtb.PixelWidth * 4;
     int size = rtb.PixelHeight * stride;
     byte[] coloredPixels = new byte[size];
     rtb.CopyPixels(coloredPixels, stride, 0);
     BitArray bits = new BitArray(width * height);
     for (int i = 0; i < size / 4; i++)
     {
         bits[i] = coloredPixels[4 * i + 3] == 0 ? false : true;
     }
     packedbitarray = new byte[Math.Max(1, bits.Length / 8)];
     bits.CopyTo(packedbitarray, 0);
 });


 dicomFile.Dataset.Add(new DicomUnsignedShort(new DicomTag(0x6000, 0x0010), width));
 dicomFile.Dataset.Add(new DicomUnsignedShort(new DicomTag(0x6000, 0x0011), height));
 dicomFile.Dataset.Add(new DicomCodeString(new DicomTag(0x6000, 0x0040), "G"));
 dicomFile.Dataset.Add(new DicomSignedShort(new DicomTag(0x6000, 0x0050), new short[] { 1, 1 }));
 dicomFile.Dataset.Add(new DicomUnsignedShort(new DicomTag(0x6000, 0x0100), 1));
 dicomFile.Dataset.Add(new DicomUnsignedShort(new DicomTag(0x6000, 0x0102), 0));
 MemoryByteBuffer buffer = new MemoryByteBuffer(packedbitarray);

 dicomFile.Dataset.Add(new DicomOtherByte(new DicomTag(0x6000, 0x3000), buffer));
 dicomFile.Save(destDicomFileName);


Have you tried asking ChatGPT? I tried with "How do I make an overlay layer in Fo-Dicom?" and it gave me an example. I don't know Fo-Dicom, but it might set you on the right path.
